# Is there any action in RDD keeps the order?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, reduce, fold

I want an action in `RDD` performance like `reduce` but don't need the operator be commutative. i.e.  I want the `result` in follow will always be `"123456789"`.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 9 map (_.toString))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[24] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val result = rdd.someAction{ _+_ }
```

Firstly, I found the `fold`. The doc of `RDD#fold` says:

> def fold(zeroValue: T)(op: (T, T) ⇒ T): T Aggregate the elements of
>   each partition, and then the results for all the partitions, using a
>   given **associative function** and a neutral "zero value"

Note that there is no ***commutative*** needed in the doc. However, the result is not as expected:

```
scala> rdd.fold(""){ _+_ }
res10: String = 312456879
```

**EDIT** I have tried as mentioned by @dk14, with no luck:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 9 map (_.toString))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[48] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> rdd.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).sortByKey().map(_._2).fold(""){ _+_ }
res22: String = 341276895

scala> rdd.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).sortByKey().map(_._2).fold(""){ _+_ }
res23: String = 914856273

scala> rdd.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).sortByKey().map(_._2).fold(""){ _+_ }
res24: String = 742539618

scala> rdd.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).sortByKey().map(_._2).fold(""){ _+_ }
res25: String = 271468359
```

Comment: You missed the next section of the docs, which describes what you're seeing: *"This behaves somewhat differently from fold operations implemented for non-distributed collections in functional languages like Scala. This fold operation may be applied to partitions individually, and then fold those results into the final result, rather than apply the fold to each element sequentially in some defined ordering. For functions that are not commutative, the result may differ from that of a fold applied to a non-distributed collection."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in reducing action that satisfies this criteria in Scala, but you can easily implement your own by combining `mapPartitions`, `collect` and local reductions:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def orderedFold[T : ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T])(zero: T)(f: (T, T) => T): T = {
  rdd.mapPartitions(iter => Iterator(iter.foldLeft(zero)(f))).collect.reduce(f)
}
```

Using combination of `collect` and `reduce` for merge instead of asynchronous and unordered method used by `fold` ensures that the global order is preserved.

This of course comes with some additional cost including:

- slightly higher memory footprint on the driver.
- significantly higher latency - we explicitly wait for all tasks to finish before we start local reduction.

Comment: Thanks for your help, does this mean that every partition **is always a  continuous sub sequence**  of the whole RDD?  Is there any document mentioned that?

Comment: Regarding docs - none that I am aware of. It is more or less constrained by the model and contracts of some ordered methods though. The real problem in Spark is how to determine overall sequence. In general there are two cases when you reason about the order a) when you use explicit sort (by contract) b) when you have input which generates deterministic ordered splits and there are no shuffles and other data movements between input and the current point.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @YuvalItzchakov `fold` does not preserve ordering in a partitioned `RDD` when combining results. To illustrate this consider coalescing the original `RDD` to one only partition,

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 9 map (_.toString)).coalesce(1)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = CoalescedRDD[27] at coalesce at <console>:27

scala> rdd.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).sortByKey().map(_._2).fold(""){ _+_ }
res4: String = 123456789

scala> rdd.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).sortByKey().map(_._2).fold(""){ _+_ }
res5: String = 123456789

scala> rdd.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).sortByKey().map(_._2).fold(""){ _+_ }
res6: String = 123456789
```

Comment: It should be noted that doing this will suffer the disadvantage of losing the parallelism abilities of the computation entirely.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov definite; with `fold`, ordering may not be preserved in a partitioned `RDD`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But the OP should be aware of that though.